# WP Query multiple select form - meta_query help

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, select

I am creating a multiple filter - as in I could filter by all the options if I wanted to do so, i.e terms, calories & price in my case.

I am having trouble with meta query args. At present I can search individually by terms or calories, and multiply by terms and calories, and terms, calories and price together but price on it's own does not effect search results?

Select:

```
                <form action="/?page_id=5" method="post">
                <?php
                    // Set min/max variables with post input data           
                    $min = $_POST['min'];   // Collect min value and set to var         
                    $max = $_POST['max'];   // Collect max value and set to var
                    // Set filter var with term post input data
                    $product_filter = $_POST['product_terms'];
                    $cal_filter = $_POST['product_cal'];
                    // Set term parameters/arguments
                    $args = array(
                        'orderby' => 'name',    
                        'order' => 'ASC',       
                        'hide_empty' => false,      
                        'parent' => 0,          
                    );
                    // Get terms with our arguments
                    $shop_terms = get_terms('shop', $args);
                        echo '<select name="product_terms[]" multiple>';
                        // Set var as an array
                        $all_product_terms = array();
                        foreach($shop_terms as $shop_term){
                            // Set all terms to our array
                            $all_product_terms[] = $shop_term->name;
                                echo '<option value="'.$shop_term->name.'">'.$shop_term->name.'</option>';
                            }
                            echo '</select>';   


                    $all_product_cal = array();                     
                    $post_args = array(   
                        'post_type' => 'shop_post',
                        'order' => 'ASC',
                        'posts_per_page'  => -1,                              
                     );
                        $posts = get_posts($post_args);
                        echo '<select name="product_cal[]" multiple>';
                            foreach ($posts as $post){
                            $keys = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'calories' );
                            // check if the custom field has a value
                            $all_product_cal[] = $keys[0];
                                if( ! empty( $keys ) ) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$keys[0].'">'.$keys[0].' cal</option>';
                                } 
                            }
                        echo 'From: &pound; <input id="shop1" type="text" name="min">';
                        echo 'To: &pound; <input id="shop2" type="text" name="max">';   
                        echo '</select>';
                        echo '<input type="submit" value="go">';
                    ?>

        </form>
```

Edit: Added complete code below
Isset and new WP_Query:

```
    $final_product_term = isset($_POST['product_terms'])  ? $product_filter : $all_product_terms; 
    $final_product_cal = isset($_POST['product_cal'])  ? $cal_filter : $all_product_cal; 

    $min_value = isset($_POST['min']) ? $min : '1';
    $max_value = isset($_POST['max']) ? $max : '100000';
    $args = array(   
    'post_type' => 'shop_post',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'shop',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $final_product_term
        )
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'calories',
            'value' => $final_product_cal,

        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
             'value' => array($min_value, $max_value),
             'type' => 'numeric',
             'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    )
 ); 
$shop_posts = new WP_Query($args);
if($shop_posts->have_posts()) : while($shop_posts->have_posts()) : $shop_posts->the_post();                 
    $met = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'price'); 
        foreach($met as $key => $val );
        echo '<div class="span3">';
            echo '<div class="inner-shop">';
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'blog-cat');
                echo '<p class="product-title">'. get_the_title($post->ID).'</p>';
                    echo '<p class="product-title">£'. $val.'</p>';               
              echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
```

Default query on page load:

```
WP_Query Object
(
[query] => Array
    (
        [post_type] => shop_post
        [order] => ASC
        [post_status] => any
        [orderby] => name
        [tax_query] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [taxonomy] => shop
                        [field] => slug
                        [terms] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Ball
                                [1] => Bars
                                [2] => Biscuits
                                [3] => Chips
                                [4] => Crackers
                                [5] => Crisps
                                [6] => Fudge
                                [7] => Granola
                            )
                    )
            )

        [meta_query] => Array
            (
                [relation] => OR
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => calories
                        [value] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 66
                                [2] => 56
                                [3] => 99
                                [4] => 70
                                [5] => 34
                                [6] => 50
                                [7] => 44
                            )
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => price
                        [value] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => 1
                                [1] => 100000
                            )

                        [type] => numeric
                        [compare] => BETWEEN
                    )
            )
    )
```

Comment: What is the value of $min and $max in your code? Also can you put the complete code in ISSET section?

Comment: @Chittaranjan They are the entered form input values. The meta_query price values do get updated correctly, but the search result does not correspond (still shows everything). Thanks

Comment: The query dump looks right. What is the format for `price` in the database?

Comment: I still don't see `$min`, `$max` collected when building the `$args` array for `WP_Query` unless the above code is placed in the same file where you have the form code. Can you please check the price values and how they are stored in the database?

Comment: @Chittaranjan "... code is placed in the same file ..." Yes it is. I have added comments for clarity. "how they are stored in the database?" Do you want to see the add_meta_boxes code?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Not quite sure what mean? meta_key = price

Comment: Is `price` a number? Or does it have other characters in it? Dashes? Currency symbols? Anything like that?

Comment: I still emphasize on this line `$min_value = isset($_POST['min']) ? $min : '1';`. I checked the above code and did not find anything wrong in that.

As per your coding if you have submitted the form, there is no reason for `$min_value` to have value 1. So now the question is: are you talking about `WP_Query` values when you just load the page or after submitting the form?

Comment: @Chittaranjan The values shown in var_dump are the WP_Qeury values. After submitting the form unless I specify price input values '$min_value' will keep it's default value of 1. Hope that helps?

Comment: @s_ha_dum "is price a number" Yes it is.

Comment: @Chittaranjan " As per your coding if you have submitted the form, there is no reason for $min_value to have value 1" What if you were to submit the form without a price value? I would expect the values to be '1,10000'? But in this case oddly the var_dump for price is empty? To re-state - when adding values to the price input field, with terms and cals also selected var_dump shows the correct price values but still all products get displayed? Thanks